# What does the FeedbackSlot size(length) mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

Some questions about Feedback:

1. as the title asked
2. A slot site that only encounters objects of a single hidden class is called `monomorphic`; if it encounters objects of two hidden classes, it is called `polymorphic`; if it is greater than 2, it is called `megamorphic`. Is that right? Then does the slot size have anything to do with polymorphic?
3. What is the **IC handler**? Is it a `<code>`?

Comment: @jmrk Could you help me? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I don't appreciate being summoned, I just volunteer to answer questions on SO when time permits. Pinging me does not make me more likely or quicker to answer any given question.

Comment: I'm really very very sorry for that, and I promise not to do this again. Thank you very much for answering my question!

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't understand the question. The class `FeedbackSlot` has no `size` and no `length`. Maybe you mean `FeedbackMetadata::GetSlotSize`? ICs of different kinds need different numbers of entries in the feedback vector (usually 1 or 2).
2. No, polymorphic state can handle more than two cases, currently up to 4 (but that could change over time). The number of feedback vector slots that an IC can use does not (and cannot!) change depending on its state. If more data needs to be stored, indirections must be used.
3. No, often it's just a Smi encoding a bit field; when that isn't enough, it's a small data class, see e.g. `class LoadHandler`: it derives from `DataHandler` which derives from `Struct`.